# Delete from table in stored procedure - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

For some reason when I use the following code outside of a stored procedure:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
DELETE FROM Customers WHERE Date=date(now());
```

It works just fine.
When I put this code in a stored procedure it doesn't delete from the table.
Any ideas why this may happen?

Comment: Because you already deleted today's customers and they are now gone? Is it a trick question?

Comment: no it's not a trick question, the customers table is just an example.

Comment: There is more to the stored proc no?

Comment: Did you try to add `Commit` inside your store procedure ?

Comment: Yes - tried commit and didn't work

Comment: can u post full code?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Can you add more information?. [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0043b/1).